# A question related to lattice theory.

Tags: lattice-orders

I am asked to show that in a Boolean Algebra
 $$(a' \lor b') \lor (a \land b \land c') \;=\; (b \land c') \lor (a' \lor b')$$
My question is - Is it absolutely okay to show this using truth table formally? 
Or else I have to use the definition ? But I guess the steps would get long and time consuming.  Any help from experts is welcome.

Comment: This isn't really a mathematical question. Its about what your homework/professor allows. You should ask them.

Comment: If you are learning things from a universal algebra standpoint, then you should avoid using truth tables. Otherwise, depending on the context in which this question is being asked (such as homework, etc.), a truth table might be okay.

Answer (score 1):

Let's examine the left hand side.

$\begin{align}(a'\vee b') \vee (a\wedge b\wedge c') & = (a\wedge b)'\wedge ((a\wedge b)\wedge c') & \textsf{de Morgan's Negation}\\ & =  & \textsf{Absorption}\\ & =  & \textsf{de Morgan's Negation}
\\ & =  & \textsf{Association and Commutation}\\ & = & \textsf{Absorption (reverse)}  \\ & = (b\wedge c') \vee (a'\vee b') & \textsf{Association and Commutation}
\end{align}$

Comment: You gave me assignment to solve. Thanks for the hint.